# Purpose of re-boxing pure value for GHCI

Tags: haskell, io-monad

Can someone explain to me why when using `ghci` I have to "re-box" the value returned by a monad?

```
 listAction=listDirectory "D:\\"
 lenAction=listAction>>=length
```

Error:

```
Couldn't match type `Int' with `IO b0'
      Expected type: [FilePath] -> IO b0
        Actual type: [FilePath] -> Int
```

I do not understand where my logic is flawed:

1. Using `listAction` gives me a `IO [FilePath]`
2. I unbox the value of `listAction` to `[FilePath]` and i give it to `length`
3. Now shouldn't `length` just print the result to the console being a pure function? Isn't it the same if i would say `length [1,2,3]`?

Why do i have to box it again? Isn't the result of the monad of type: `[FilePath]` and if so why can it not print the result?

```
lenAction=list>>=return . length
```

Comment: Re: (3): no, `length` does not implicitly print its result. If that's what you want, you must ask for it: `listAction >>= print . length`, for example. Likely this confusion has arisen because, to be user-friendly, ghci *usually* wraps pure things with an implicit call to `print` for you without you noticing. It will wrap a `print` around the entire expression you entered (e.g. it would be okay inserting `print (listAction >>= length)` if that type-checked) but won't reach deep inside your expression to try to guess where a `print` should go.

Answer (score 5):

This just a type error.

The type of `>>=` (when used with `IO`) is

```
(>>=) :: IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> IO b
```

That is, the second argument must be a function that returns a value of type `IO something`. `length` doesn't have such a type, so the type checker complains.

As you show, `return :: a -> IO a` can be used to lift a value into `IO`. That is one way to solve the problem.

Another way is to use `fmap`:

```
fmap length listAction
```

This works because `fmap` (when used with `IO`) is

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> IO a -> IO b
```

(Other ways of doing the same thing include `liftM length listAction` and `length <$> listAction`.)

Comment: `liftM` is typically used only to define `fmap`. Other uses come off as a bit old-fashioned.